# Setting a Attribute for Every Request (Spring REST)

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, java-8

I am doing a rest app in spring and i have a log out method like below. I dont have knowledge on spring so i just searched around and made this.

```
@RestController
public class LogoutController {

@Autowired
private DatabaseService databaseService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/myApp/user/logout", method = GET, produces = {"application/xml"})
public Users performLogout(@RequestHeader("AuthenticationID") String authID, HttpServletRequest request) throws DatatypeConfigurationException {
    return handleLogout(request, authID);
}

private Users handleLogout(HttpServletRequest request, String authID) throws DatatypeConfigurationException {
    LogService.info(this.getClass().getName(), "Received Logout Request");
    final UsersXMLBuilder usersXMLBuilder = new UsersXMLBuilder();
    Users usersXML = usersXMLBuilder.buildDefaultUsersTemplate();
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    AppUtilities utils = new AppUtilities(); 

    try {
        //Checking with RegEX
        if (utils.isValidUUID(authToken)) {
            //Get User Login Record from DB By the AuthID and Delete It
            //Invalidate The Session
            session.invalidate();
            LogService.info(this.getClass().getName(), "Session Invaliated");

        } else {
            LogService.info(this.getClass().getName(), "Invalid AuthID Found. Not a Valid UUID");
            usersXML.setResponseCode(-5);
            usersXML.setResponseText("User Session is Not Valid");
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LogService.error(this.getClass().getName(), ex);
        usersXML.setResponseCode(-4);
        usersXML.setResponseText("Error Occured!");
        return usersXML;
    } finally {
        LogService.info(this.getClass().getName(), "LogOut Process Finished");
    }
    return usersXML;
 }
}
```

Questions

---

1- Is it possible i can return a XML message when spring gives white label error page when i pass no authentication ID in request.

2- How can i get the Authentication Header and check it for null and give message that AuthID is missing.

3- How can i set a attribute explicitly and check for it in every controller that if it exists or not.

4- I plan to have a table where i can store user login time and give a session 10 mins time and Update it more 10 mins if i get any request from the user with the AuthID. So can i have a class or method which can check any incoming request? so i can detect the AuthID and Update My table.

Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an interceptor for that : http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor

The interceptor will run for every request. It can stop the request and do a response itself.

Comment: Thank you. This looks good. So i can Set Request Properties in preHandle() and get them inside any RestController?

Comment: The interceptor can populate the request attribute. So the controller can retrieve it.